# Could not resolve 'state1' from state 'state2'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im transitioning from one state to another using $state.go() like below:

**$state.go('menuItem.list');**

This causes following error.

***Could not resolve 'menuItem.list' from state 'branches.view'***

Below are the state providers for menuItem and branch modules.

**module : branch**

```
.state('branches', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/branches',
  template: '<ui-view/>'
})
.state('branches.list', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'modules/branches/client/views/list-branches.client.view.html',
  controller: 'branchesListController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
.state('branches.view', {
  url: '/:branchId',
  templateUrl: 'modules/branches/client/views/view-branch.client.view.html',
  controller: 'branchesController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

**module : menuItem**

```
.state('menuItems', {
  abstract: true,
  url: '/menuItems',
  template: '<ui-view/>'
})
.state('menuItems.list', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'modules/menuItems/client/views/list-menuItems.client.view.html',
  controller: 'menuItemsListController',
  controllerAs: 'vm'
})
```

Comment: your `branches.view` state is not added or mentioned in main module.

Comment: have you include both routing/state configurations in main js config file or in main module?

Comment: I meant the main module file

Answer (score 1):

This way you can all modules in new module file

```
angular.module('branches.modules', [
    'branches', 'branches.list', 'branches.view', 'menuItems','menuItems.list'
]);
```

and add that in your main app.js or app.module.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'branches.modules']);
```

Answer (score 0):

yo can use code below :

**module : branch**

```
.state('branches', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/branches',
      template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('branches.list', {
      url: '',
      views: {
            templateUrl: 'modules/branches/client/views/list-branches.client.view.html',
            controller: 'branchesListController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
          }
      })
    .state('branches.view', {
      url: '/:branchId',
      views: { 
            templateUrl: 'modules/branches/client/views/view-branch.client.view.html',
            controller: 'branchesController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        })
```

**module : menuItem**

```
    .state('menuItems', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/menuItems',
            template: '<ui-view/>'
       })
     .state('menuItems.list', {
       url: '',
       views:{
                  templateUrl: 'modules/menuItems/client/views/list-menuItems.client.view.html',
                  controller: 'menuItemsListController',
                  controllerAs: 'vm'
              }    
})
```

you must use views in state 
**Good Luck**